# Improving my Dockerfile build times using multiple FROM statements

Tags: docker, dockerfile, google-cloud-build

Is it possible to make my docker builds faster.

I have seen Dockerfile's with multiple FROM statements, is that something that would make sense to do with my Dockerfile?

```
FROM ruby:2.5-alpine

RUN apk update && apk --update add \
 build-base \
 nodejs \
 postgresql-dev \
 tzdata \
 imagemagick \
 ruby-dev \
 libxml2-dev \
 libxslt-dev \
 pcre-dev \
 libffi-dev  

# yarn
ENV PATH=/root/.yarn/bin:$PATH
RUN apk add --virtual build-yarn curl && \
    touch ~/.bashrc && \
    curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | sh && \
    apk del build-yarn

# app
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile ./
RUN gem install bundler -v 2.0.1
RUN gem uninstall bundler --version '<2.0.0'
RUN gem install nokogiri -v '1.10.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
RUN bundle install --binstubs
```

I am using google cloud build and registry, so I can store an intermediate docker image and store it with its registry.

Comment: if you want to make it faster you can build a intermediate version of your container where you already added most dependencies and files that dont change as often in your case you probably want `RUN apk update && apk --update add \
 build-base \
 nodejs \
 postgresql-dev \
 tzdata \
 imagemagick \
 ruby-dev \
 libxml2-dev \
 libxslt-dev \
 pcre-dev \
 libffi-dev  ` to be in a base image that way it will only validate the version and not download it all each time oh and the yarn stuff seems wuite static as well oO

Answer (score 2):

Docker [multi stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) can help to reduce the size of the final image, but won't reduce the time of your build.

---

What does reduce the time of the build is to understand how Docker build cache works under the hood. Read [Leverage build cache](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache) from the Docker [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/) documentation.

I'm not familiar with Ruby, but it seems to me that the `Gemfile` is only useful for the `bundle install` command, and ignored for the `gem install` commands. If that is the case, you would be better moving the `COPY Gemfile ./` line so it appears right before `RUN bundle install --binstubs`. The reason is that every time your Gemfile changes, *docker build* would recognize the situation and invalidate any layer following that instruction from the build cache.

---

Now everything I said earlier is valid as long as you run the successive builds on the same machine.

Since you are using Google Cloud Build, you will run each build on a new clean environment everytime, and thus, won't have any docker intermediate layers in cache... unless you configure Google Cloud Build to save and restore your cache.

From Google Cloud Build [Best practices for speeding up builds](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/speeding-up-builds) documentation, you will find instructions on how to enable the [Kaniko](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/kaniko-cache) cache which will take care of saving those docker build intermediate layers.